# Need help in php JSON conversion

Tags: php, json

I am trying to convert php array to JSON format, I am not getting as desired, please provide a solution.

I am getting data from database

```
$banks =   SELECT bankname FROM re_banks.
```

And I am converting to JSON with below code.

```
$return_arr = Array();

foreach($banks as $row){
array_push($return_arr,$row);
}
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

output is:

```
[{"bankname":"Allahabad Bank"},{"bankname":"Andhra Bank Ltd"}]
```

Output I need is :

```
[{"Allahabad Bank":"Allahabad Bank"},{"Allahabad Bank":"Andhra Bank Ltd"}]
```

Please help me.

Regards,
Ashok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach($banks as $row){
  $return_arr[$row['bankname']] = $row['bankname'];
}
```

This will set the key and the value equal to the same text.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
foreach($banks as $row){
    $return_arr[$row['key']] = $row['key'];
}

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

The `'key'` you need to supply above is probably `'bankname'`, but it could also be index `0`.  That depends on how you're fetching the data from the database.